# need to move data from one field to another, within the same table

Tags: mysql

I want to move all data from field_id_41 into field_id_380, where weblog_id = 191

Those two fields belong to the same table: exp_weblog_data

I do not want to run anything without asking here, I started to put this together:

```
UPDATE 
  exp_weblog_data 
SET 
  field_id_380 = (SELECT field_id_41 FROM exp_weblog_data 
  WHERE (field_id_41 != '' and weblog_id = 191)) 
WHERE 
  weblog_id = 191
```

Comment: Is `weblog_id` a primary key or a unique key?

Comment: Do you mean `move` or `copy`? Should column `field_id_41` be empty afterwards?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Really no need for the subquery. You can just take the value for the other column in the same row, and set it in the first column:

```
UPDATE 
  exp_weblog_data 
SET 
  field_id_380 =field_id_41 
WHERE 
  weblog_id = 191
AND 
  field_id_41 != ''
```

Comment: Assuming he wants data from the same row only...the OP specified same table but not same row.

Comment: @RedFilter: correct, his "from one field to another" made me assume this. Else, a join or subquery is needed, but I'm curious to what he is trying to achieve then...

Comment: To me "move" means field_id_41 is empty afterwards, so: SET field_id_380 =field_id_41, field_id_41 = '' ...

Comment: for each row, I want to move its respective data from field_id_41 to field_id_380

Comment: It would be great if people made the distinction between move and copy consequently. Unfortunately, when my boss told me I could have a bigger car or a promotion, he also meant xor instead of or.

Answer (score 5):

maybe like this:

```
UPDATE 
  exp_weblog_data 
SET 
  field_id_380 =field_id_41,   field_id_41 = ''
WHERE 
  weblog_id = 191
AND 
  field_id_41 != ''
```

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do if I were you is make a backup of that database and host it on another(or the same) server. Once you've done that you can literally go nuts and experiment at will without fear of losing any real data. That query looks fine to me, though.

Comment: I would think that's implicit in any experimentation with a database