# How to move one fields data from another field within same mysql database table?

Tags: php, mysql, kohana

In mysql database in `user` table. I have a field named `age` but now I would like to move all the contents of `age` field to newly created field named `age_min`. How can I do that? Thanks in advance..

Comment: check this it may be help `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7435309/need-to-move-data-from-one-field-to-another-within-the-same-table` and this `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001939/copy-values-from-one-column-to-another-in-the-same-table`

Comment: just rename your column `age` to `age_min`.

Comment: Thanks @user2936213 ..  It was so simple but I was confused..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```
 UPDATE `user` SET age_min=age;
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply do:

```
Update table set age=age_min;
```

It will replicate the value of the field age to the field age_min

Comment: This will do the opposite.

Comment: Oopss... my bad... 
Advice: never write a query too fast.

Answer (score 1):

try this qry...

```
update `user` set `age_min` = `age`;
```

Answer (score 1):

This Should do:

```
UPDATE user SET age_min = age;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could copy all of the data to the new column:

```
UPDATE `user` SET `age_men` = `age`
```

OR you could just rename the existing column:

```
ALTER TABLE `user` CHANGE `age` `age_min` int
```

(you may have to drop the new column you just created in order to run the above query, if so, do this: `ALTER TABLE user DROP age_min`

SQL Fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dfe84/2

Answer (score 0):

Run this query:

```
UPDATE `user` SET `age_min` = `age`
```